# Comparisons of Strings in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I would like to compare two CLOBS from the same column. To do this I understand that I must first convert them to varchar.

The strings that I would like to retrieve from my query always have the structure that one string is a subset of the other string. This means that one string contains the other one. Always starting from 1...n

So if string1 has length k and string2 has length n where k < n then string2 matches string1 up to k. This is always the case. n != k

Anyway below is my code, I am having trouble comapring the CLOBs with each other. I never get any results. My method so far was to convert the longer string into the shorter and then check if they match. This however doesn't work. I don't get any results.

```
SELECT 
 s1.signaturedescription,
 s2.signaturedescription,
 s1.signdate,
 s2.signdate
FROM
signature s1,
signature s2
WHERE
s1.signatureid = 'VerificationSignature'
AND
s2.signatureid = 'EbrCorrectActualValues'
AND
 s1.username = s2.username
AND 
 dbms_lob.compare(s1.signaturedescription, s2.signaturedescription, 106, 1, 1) = 0;
```

The code above works, however I would like to replace the "106" with the length of s1.signaturedescription. I tried accomplishing this by doing the following:

```
dbms_lob.compare(s1.signaturedescription, s2.signaturedescription, length((TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(s1.signaturedescription,1,4000)))), 1, 1) = 0;
```

This however does not work. I do not get any returned results. Do you know how I can change the 106 to the length of the s1.signaturedescription?

Thank you

Comment: "*two clobs from the same column*" doesn't make sense. A column can only be a single CLOB

Comment: I guess the correct verbiage is that you have one CLOB which you want to break down in two CLOBs or VARCHARs and then compare them. A single column can never have two CLOBs in it, its always a single CLOB.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I dunno, it makes sense to me. The OP is saying that `signature.signaturedescription` is a CLOB, and (s)he wants to compare two different `signature` records based on that CLOB. So, "two CLOBS from the same column" means "the values of a certain CLOB column in each of two fields".

Comment: Take a look at dbms_lob.compare() as it can compare two clobs and has parameters on where to start and end the comparison for each clob.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for your help I replaced the last line of the code with this line: "dbms_lob.compare(s1.signaturedescription, s2.signaturedescription, 200, 1, 1) = 0;" However I would like to replace the 200 with the length of s1.signaturedescription, my question is how do I do this? I tried replacing the 200 with the following code: LENGTHB((TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(s1.signaturedescription,1,4000)))) But this does not give me any results. Please advise how I can fix it. Thanks

Comment: @Brian please see my edit above

Answer (score 0):

You should use dbms_lob_compare function.

Read the following link about this:

http://dba-oracle.com/t_compare_clob_columns_dbms_lob.htm

Comment: I am now using the compare function, please see my edits/problem above

Comment: look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm there is a part about compare and they explain how to compare a part. There is also the function dbms_lob.getlength